# How can I display "«" in Japanese? Shift JIS encoding

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, ascii

I have text and I want to add '«' at the start and '»' at the end of the string.
for example: «MyText».

```
#define START_MARKER                                    0x00AB  // '«'
#define END_MARKER                                      0x00BB  // '»'

char startMarker[2], endMarker[2];
sprintf(startMarker, "%c",START_MARKER);
sprintf(endMarker, "%c",END_MARKER);
const UTF16String unicodeStartMarker = ai::UnicodeString(startMarker).as_ASUnicode();
const UTF16String unicodeEndMarker = ai::UnicodeString(endMarker).as_ASUnicode();
sUnicodePlaceholder = unicodeStartMarker + UTF8String(sFieldName).GetUnicodeString() + unicodeEndMarker;
```

It works for all the languages except Japanese.
I get different character as you can see below:

[image]

The character "«" is also defined : "U+00ab" but with suffix SJIS (character encoding for the Japanese language)
Do you have any idea how can I display "«" in Japanese?
thanks!!

Comment: Try `《》` instead of `«»`: `《` (U+300A,  *Left Double Angle Bracket*)
and `》` (U+300B,  *Right Double Angle Bracket*).

Comment: The Unicode code points U+00AB and U+00BB are not supported by the SJIS encoding, but the ones pointed out by JosefZ are.  In SJIS, U+300A is encoded as `81 73` (hexadecimal) and U+300B is `81 74`.

Comment: @Mark, your comment is the correct answer. Resubmit it as an answer rather than a comment, and I for one will be ready to upvote you.

Comment: thank you all!! @MarkTolonen @ JosefZ @ Jim DeLaHunt. 
I changed to: #define START_MARKER 0x300A // '«'   and also changed to : #define START_MARKER 0x8173 // '«' but still I don't get the correct character, can you please advise?

Comment: @jim It's not a complete answer because the OP's code isn't a [mcve] and I don't know exactly what they need to fix it.  If the terminal used expects SHIFT JIS-encoded bytes, then I guess `char startMarker[3] = {0x81,0x73,0x0};` might be needed, but I don't know what library is being used for the UTF8/16String types.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I see what you mean about OP's code not being a minimal reproducible example. And, I did not notice before that you have about 1.4E+26 reputation, so perhaps an extra +10 from an upvoted answer does not motivate like it used to. :-)

Comment: I am not clear on what you really want to know.  Could you please say what result you expect from your code, and what result you get? What language is the code in? What libraries are you calling?  If you expect output in Shift-JIS encoding, why do you call a function that apparently generates strings in UTF-8 encoding? What program displays the "字形" palette, and how does it relate to your code? In summary, edit your question to make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as @MarkTolonen suggests.